# Is it possible to call a deployed contracts function from inside a second contract

Tags: solidity

For example,

contract a has a function called mint. - contract a is already deployed.
contract b has a function called mint, but we want contract b to call the mint function from contract a instead of creating a new mint function.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.

[Smart Contract Programmer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJWh7F3AFyQ_x01VKzr9eyA) has nice videos on this and many other topics.

Specifically, the video [Call Other Contracts | Solidity 0.8](https://youtu.be/6aQErpWPLbk) has the information you need.